# Regex to match phone numbers that contain ()- at any position

Tags: java, regex

I am struggling to create a java regex that matches phone numbers in the following format :

`+49(173)46-5847`

In order to match this string I used this regex :

`^(+(d+)((d+))(d+)-(d+))`

How should an expression look like that matches the whole string(in this case a phone number) when parentheses,hyphens or spaces are found at any position, independent of the length of the string?

The following formats should not be matched :

`+49173465847` or `0049173465847`

Thanks!

Comment: You need to escape the `+`, `(` and `)`, otherwise they are seen as regex operators.

Comment: If you don't need the capturing groups, try `^\+\d+\(\d+\)\d+-\d+$`.

Comment: I think you need to better define your problem. Should parentheses be allowed around any groups of numbers? Around all groups? Where should hyphens and spaces be allowed? Is the following format okay: + 4-9 -1(7(3-4 6- -5(8)4 -7`. Why or why not? Sometimes, the most difficult part of coding is fully defining your problem before you try to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these two look aheads to ensure, you have a parenthesis having one or more digits inside `(?=\d.*\(\d+\))` and another look ahead to ensure if at all you have hyphen, then they are between two digits only and not at the end `(?=.*\d(-\d+)*$)`. Then collect all data using this allowed character set `[\d()-]*`. The regex you need to use is following,

```
^\+?(?=\d.*\(\d+\))(?=.*\d(-\d+)*$)[\d()-]*$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UqP2Uj/1)**

Java codes,

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("+49(173)46-5847", "+49173465847", "0049173465847", "+49-(173)-(465)-847",
        "+49-(173)465-8471", "49-(173)465-8471", "+49-(173)465-8471", "+-49-(173)465-8471",
        "+49-(173)465-8471-");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\+?(?=\\d.*\\(\\d+\\))(?=.*\\d(-\\d+)*$)[\\d()-]*$");
list.forEach(x -> System.out.println(
        x + " --> " + ((Pattern.matches("^\\+?(?=\\d.*\\(\\d+\\))(?=.*\\d(-\\d+)*$)[\\d()-]*$", x)) ? "Is Valid"
                : "Is Not Valid")));
```

Prints,

```
+49(173)46-5847 --> Is Valid
+49173465847 --> Is Not Valid
0049173465847 --> Is Not Valid
+49-(173)-(465)-847 --> Is Valid
+49-(173)465-8471 --> Is Valid
49-(173)465-8471 --> Is Valid
+49-(173)465-8471 --> Is Valid
+-49-(173)465-8471 --> Is Not Valid
+49-(173)465-8471- --> Is Not Valid
```

Comment: This also matches on nonsense strings like "+49-(1(7)3)-(465)-8-----47", "+49-(173)465-8(4)))(()()71", "49-(173)4((6))5-8471", "+49-(173)465-8(-)-(-)-(471", etc.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted because I needed to match all nonsense. I use this in a contact center platform for callbacks and this way I can prevent to schedule a callback with an invalid number. The call cannot be initiated towards a phone number containing brackets, hyphens and so on. Only digits and + is allowed. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You might need a more robust matching algorithm for this. Presumably you don't want to allow matches like

```
+49)4(5321)3595)259((
```

But there is nothing in your description which prevents that ("parentheses,hyphens or spaces are found at any position"). To exclude solutions like this, you'll need to keep track of whether or not you're inside a parenthetical expression at a given character index (whether you've passed a '(' character already) and if so, to not allow any more '(' characters until you see a ')'.

This requires keeping track of a particular *state*, which is not possible with regex alone.

Answer (score 0):

Try This please :
^(+)((()*\d*())*(-)*)*(((()+\d+())+(-)*))+(\d)*((()*\d*())*(-)*)*

Hope this helps.